# In Amazon Mechanical Turk, Batch HITs remain in mTurk website UI Manager after approving HITs with API

Tags: mechanicalturk

I am currently creating a Batch Project via the Amazon Mechanical Turk website (http://requester.mturk.com). After all the HITs have been completed, I download the CSV and approve or reject the hits.

I am then iterating through the CSV and using the mTurk API to call ApproveAssignment or RejectAssignment on the AssignmentId for each row.

When looking as a Worker (in which I completed my own HITs for testing), I see that HITs have been properly approved or rejected. However when looking as the requester it appears that none of the assignments have been approved or denied and the batch project looks like it is still waiting to be reviewed.

Any thoughts? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue. Once you operate on a HIT via the API, the batch interface no long works correctly.

The [Manage HITs Individually](https://requester.mturk.com/mturk/manageHITs?) page should still be updated correctly, though.

Comment: Do you have any links that share more information about this known issue?